# A better JavaScript version of addslashes and stripslashes?

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

I am using these 2 functions:

http://javascript.about.com/library/bladdslash.htm

But JSLint complains 'Bad Escapement' on this line:

```
str=str.replace(/\\0/g,'\0');
```

[Edit]

I converted to 2 lines, and now the first line is the one that fails JLint:

```
var rep = '\0';
str=str.replace(/\\0/g,rep);
```

So it is the

> '\0'

can you help? I could try something but I want to understand what is going on.

[/Edit]

Can you make a better version and explain?

I would like a version that passes JSLint and still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `'\0'` with `String.fromCharCode(0)`.

Alternatively, if you don't expect your data to contain embedded nulls (which it *really* shouldn't), you can remove that line entirely.